# How to run multiple WSL commands from a Windows NodeJS process?

Tags: node.js, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have a Windows NodeJS process which has to invoke some Linux commands via WSL. In a normal WSL bash session, we would just execute these commands one after the other:

```
user@pc:/mnt/c/Users/user$ command1 args1
user@pc:/mnt/c/Users/user$ command2 args2
```

However, when calling WSL via `wsl command1 args1` and then `wsl command2 args2`, the results from the first call do not affect the second call. These are two sessions, not one.

I tried it like this: The first command is a `virtualenv` `activate` call, the second one is the execution of a Python script:

```
import { child_process } from 'mz';

child_process.spawn('wsl', ['source /path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate', 'which python'])
```

does not work, because the two arguments are interpreted as one command each (`source /path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate: No such file or directory`).

I also tried

```
child_process.spawn('wsl', ['source /path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate && which python'])
```

and

```
child_process.spawn('wsl', ['source /path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate `&`& which python'])
```

Does not work either.

How can I batch these two commands so that WSL and bash understand which commands belong together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it works by sending all commands and parameters separately, and concatenating the different commands via a separate "command" `&&`:

```
child_process.spawn('wsl', ['source', '/path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate', '&&', 'which', 'python'])
```